# HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession still true after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to redirect to the same page with different query string parameters

```
HttpResponse resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;

resp.Redirect(landingPagePath)
```

To avoid further processing after redirection i check if

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession == false
```

but for some reason i found that this is not always the case after redirection

can anyone please tell why is this happening

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to avoid further processing (your description is vague), maybe you could pass an additional parameter to indicate that you just redirected.. and determine what to do based on the value of that parameter..

Comment: I think you've missed a double negative?  It looks to me like the question is asking why the session is sometimes "not not new" after the redirect.  
Regardless, an extra parameter sounds more suitable...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use your `Page.IsPostBack` flag instead? It will be false when you redirect the page back on itself with the modified querystring.